Forge Test Contract Transfer EvmError: Revert
Context
Trying to run through the same tests for the default contract for Hardhat's basic Lock.sol, and getting errors with .transfer.
Tested this in Remix and the functionality works, but under the tests it keeps giving EvmError: Revert.
System

forge 0.2.0 (70ef94a 2024-08-23T00:24:46.787262000Z)
macOS (Apple Silicon)

Code
File: ./src/Lock.sol - Hardhat Lock Contract Example
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.24;

// Uncomment this line to use console.log
// import "hardhat/console.sol";

contract Lock {
    uint public unlockTime;
    address payable public owner;

    event Withdrawal(uint amount, uint when);

    constructor(uint _unlockTime) payable {
        require(
            block.timestamp < _unlockTime,
            "Unlock time should be in the future"
        );

        unlockTime = _unlockTime;
        owner = payable(msg.sender);
    }

    function withdraw() public {
        // Uncomment this line, and the import of "hardhat/console.sol", to print a log in your terminal
        // console.log("Unlock time is %o and block timestamp is %o", unlockTime, block.timestamp);

        require(block.timestamp >= unlockTime, "You can't withdraw yet");
        require(msg.sender == owner, "You aren't the owner");

        emit Withdrawal(address(this).balance, block.timestamp);

        owner.transfer(address(this).balance);
    }
}

File: ./test/Lock.t.sol
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.24;

import {Test, console} from "forge-std/Test.sol";
import {Lock} from "../src/Lock.sol";

    Lock public lock;
    uint256 public unlockTime;

    /// @dev Set up the Lock contract
    function setUp() public {
      unlockTime = block.timestamp + 1 days;
      lock = new Lock{value: 1 ether}(unlockTime);
    }
    
    /// @dev Verifies that the contract can withdraw after the unlock time
    function test_WithdrawBalance() public {
      vm.warp(block.timestamp + 1 days);
      lock.withdraw();
      assertEq(address(lock).balance, 0 ether);
    }
}

Steps To Reproduce
# FROM: ./

forge test --match-path test/Lock.t.sol -vvv;

# [Test Results]:
# [⠊] Compiling...
# No files changed, compilation skipped
# 
# Ran 1 test for test/Lock.t.sol:LockTest
# [FAIL. Reason: EvmError: Revert] test_WithdrawBalance() (gas: 20954)
# Traces:
#   [20954] LockTest::test_WithdrawBalance()
#     ├─ [0] VM::warp(86401 [8.64e4])
#     │   └─ ← [Return] 
#     ├─ [12805] Lock::withdraw()
#     │   ├─ emit Withdrawal(amount: 1000000000000000000 [1e18], when: 86401 [8.64e4])
#     │   ├─ [45] LockTest::fallback{value: 1000000000000000000}()
#     │   │   └─ ← [Revert] EvmError: Revert
#     │   └─ ← [Revert] EvmError: Revert
#     └─ ← [Revert] EvmError: Revert
# 
# Suite result: FAILED. 0 passed; 1 failed; 0 skipped; finished in 378.63µs (93.71µs CPU time)
# 
# Ran 1 test suite in 447.94ms (378.63µs CPU time): 0 tests passed, 1 failed, 0 skipped (1 total tests)
# 
# Failing tests:
# Encountered 1 failing test in test/Lock.t.sol:LockTest
# [FAIL. Reason: EvmError: Revert] test_WithdrawBalance() (gas: 20954)
# 
# Encountered a total of 1 failing tests, 0 tests succeeded

Example Successful Remix Code Tests
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.24;

contract Lock {
    uint public unlockTime;
    address payable public owner;

    event Withdrawal(uint amount, uint when);

    constructor() payable {
        owner = payable(msg.sender);
    }

    function withdraw() public {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "You aren't the owner");
        emit Withdrawal(address(this).balance, block.timestamp);
        owner.transfer(address(this).balance);
    }
}


I found the solution. I need to prank the interactions.
File: ./test/Lock.t.sol
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.24;

import {Test, console} from "forge-std/Test.sol";
import {Lock} from "../src/Lock.sol";

contract LockTest is Test {
    Lock public lock;
    uint256 public unlockTime;
    address owner = 0x5B38Da6a701c568545dCfcB03FcB875f56beddC4;
    uint256 ownerInitialBalance = 2 ether;

    /// @dev Set up the Lock contract
    function setUp() public {
      unlockTime = block.timestamp + 1 days;
      vm.deal(owner, ownerInitialBalance);
      vm.startPrank(owner);
      lock = new Lock{value: 1 ether}(unlockTime);
      vm.stopPrank();
    }

    /// @dev Verifies that the contract can withdraw after the unlock time
    function test_WithdrawBalance() public {
      vm.startPrank(owner);
      vm.warp(block.timestamp + 1 days);
      lock.withdraw();
      assertEq(address(lock).balance, 0 ether);
      assertEq(owner.balance, ownerInitialBalance);
      vm.stopPrank();
    }
}

Script run:
# FROM: ./

forge test --match-path test/Lock.t.sol -vvv;

# [Expected Output]:
# [⠊] Compiling...
# [⠒] Compiling 1 files with Solc 0.8.25
# [⠢] Solc 0.8.25 finished in 1.07s
# Compiler run successful!
# 
# Ran 1 test for test/Lock.t.sol:LockTest
# [PASS] test_WithdrawBalance() (gas: 29583)
# Traces:
#   [29583] LockTest::test_WithdrawBalance()
#     ├─ [0] VM::startPrank(0x5B38Da6a701c568545dCfcB03FcB875f56beddC4)
#     │   └─ ← [Return] 
#     ├─ [0] VM::warp(86401 [8.64e4])
#     │   └─ ← [Return] 
#     ├─ [15256] Lock::withdraw()
#     │   ├─ emit Withdrawal(amount: 1000000000000000000 [1e18], when: 86401 [8.64e4])
#     │   ├─ [0] 0x5B38Da6a701c568545dCfcB03FcB875f56beddC4::fallback{value: 1000000000000000000}()
#     │   │   └─ ← [Stop] 
#     │   └─ ← [Stop] 
#     ├─ [0] VM::assertEq(0, 0) [staticcall]
#     │   └─ ← [Return] 
#     ├─ [0] VM::assertEq(2000000000000000000 [2e18], 2000000000000000000 [2e18]) [staticcall]
#     │   └─ ← [Return] 
#     ├─ [0] VM::stopPrank()
#     │   └─ ← [Return] 
#     └─ ← [Stop] 
# 
# Suite result: ok. 1 passed; 0 failed; 0 skipped; finished in 376.63µs (81.08µs CPU time)
# 
# Ran 1 test suite in 150.44ms (376.63µs CPU time): 1 tests passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped (1 total tests)

